# Jarvis Connection Bluetooth

Tags: xamarin.forms, thermal-printer

I downloaded this package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Jarvis.Connections.Bluetooth.Thermal.Printer/ , it's a full library to work with thermal printers and bluetooth, but I couldn't find a way to implement it. Is there some example or documentation for it?

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Jarvis.Connections.Bluetooth.Thermal.Printer/1.0.1.3/ContactOwners

Comment: @Jason thanks for the help, I didn't tried it yet because they could delay to answer me, so I post here (I don't like to do this kind of post, but I keep with no options to find it).